# Query for key with specific value from different objects of array in JSONPath

Tags: java, jsonpath

```
{
  "dataObject": [
    {
      "id": 263626,
      "role": {
        "id": 12054,
        "name": "Edit",
        "description": ""
      },
      "resource": {
        "id": 5756,
        "type": "resource"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 263364,
      "role": {
        "id": 12054,
        "name": "Edit",
        "description": ""
      },
      "resource": {
        "id": 5728,
        "type": "resource"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a JSON object which looks like this. I need to extract the json object from `dataObject` which has `name:Edit` and id:`5756`. 
How can I achieve this using JSON path?
Tried `$..[?(@.name="Edit", @.id=5756)]` which didn't work.

Java code:

```
JsonPath.parse(json).read("$..[?(@.name='Edit'), (@.id=5756)]")
```

Comment: Please show the java code that you have tried.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Maybe it's because attribute `name="Edit"` in object `role`, but `id=5756` in object `resource`, so you trying to point two different objects?

Comment: Yes. they are part of 2 objects which are part of one object in the array.

Comment: Try `$..[?((@.resource.id == 5756) && (@.role.name == 'Edit'))]` In my unit test seems like working.

Comment: I used `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0` for test.

Comment: Yep. That works like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use parent object name and logical operator `AND`. The resulting path will be

`$..[?((@.resource.id == 5756) && (@.role.name == 'Edit'))]`.

It's work for me in unit test with `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0`

```
@Test
public void testParse() {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"dataObject\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": 263626,\n" +
            "      \"role\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": 12054,\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"Edit\",\n" +
            "        \"description\": \"\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"resource\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": 5756,\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"resource\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": 263364,\n" +
            "      \"role\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": 12054,\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"Edit\",\n" +
            "        \"description\": \"\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"resource\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": 5728,\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"resource\"\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    DocumentContext parse = JsonPath.parse(json);
    Object read = parse.read("$..[?((@.resource.id == 5756) && (@.role.name == 'Edit'))]");
    assertNotNull(read);
}
```